# Linked List Insert Node - How to Reference Arguments

Tags: c++, list, pointers, hyperlink

So I have a Linked List and I pass in some arguments, in this case it is a box and the parameters are length, width and height. What I want is to be able to print out the values put in. Currently, my Pointer is the volume of the boxes which is the length, width and height multiplied. When a node is behind or in front of another, I want it to display for example `10x2x5 inserted at front of list` and not `100 inserted at front of list`.

Code for inserting Nodes:

```
template <typename T>void LinkList<T>::insertNode(const T &length, const T &width, const T &height) {
LinkNode<T>*newPtr = getNewNode(length * width * height);
bool inserted = false;

if (isEmpty() || (newPtr->data < firstPtr->data)) {
    newPtr->nextPtr = firstPtr;
    firstPtr = newPtr;
    cout << newPtr->data << " inserted at front of list\n";
}
else {
    LinkNode<T>*currentPtr = firstPtr;
    while (currentPtr->nextPtr && !inserted) {
        if (newPtr->data < currentPtr->nextPtr->data) {
            cout << newPtr->data << " inserted before " << currentPtr->nextPtr->data << endl;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
            inserted = true;
        }
        else {
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
    }
    if (!inserted) {
        currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
        cout << newPtr->data << " inserted at end of list\n";
    }
}
}
```

Code for printing values:

```
template<typename T>void LinkList<T>::print()const {
if (isEmpty()) {
    cout << "No boxes in list!\n";
}
else {
    LinkNode<T>*currentPtr = firstPtr;
    cout << "Your boxes are: ";
    while (currentPtr != NULL) {
        cout << currentPtr->data << ' ';
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
}
```

Node class:

```
//Template ListNode class definition.
#ifndef LINKNODE_H
#define LINKNODE_H

template <typename T> class LinkList;

template <typename T>class LinkNode{
    friend class LinkNode <T>; 

    public:
        LinkNode(const T &); 
        T getData()const;
        T data;
        LinkNode <T> *nextPtr;
};

template <typename T>LinkNode <T>::LinkNode(const T &info):data(info),     nextPtr(NULL){
    // Empty body
}

template <typename T>T LinkNode<T>::getData()const{
    return data;
}

#endif
```

Comment: You will need to store the three values (length, width and height) in your `Node` as separate variables.  But you haven't shown your `Node` class.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add my node class now!

Comment: So instead of `T data`, I would use `T length, T width, T height`? Then in my print method, I would use those variables?

Comment: I recommend placing `length, width` and `height` inside your `T` structure.  The length, width and height are *members* of the node, not separate nodes.

Comment: Would those changes go in my node class? I'm completely new to Link List and find the concept somewhat confusing. When you say inside my `T` structure, would that mean I should add `length, width and height` to the class `LinkNode` under where the public members are? Or would those members belong to the structure `T`?

Comment: So, I guess a better question would be is it possible to give my structure `T` properties and access those properties when calling for the current pointer in `print()`?